# How to sum the values in one row even if the other value is empty

Tags: sql, concatenation

```
select  case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then sum(Value)     else null end as Value , 
     case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then sum(Discount)  else null end as Discount , 
     case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then sum(Net)       else null end as Net , 
     case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then sum(Paid)      else null end as Paid , 
     case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then sum(Rest)      else null end as Rest
```

Comment: Hi . please take a minute to format your code such that is is readable  there is a button to select a chunk of test and mark  it as code. You also need to post the table ddl, example table data and expected output, and tag with database version.  Also read [ask] and [mcve]  thanks

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write. Can you fix line breaks, and the indentation.

Comment: Is there a `FROM` clause? A `GOUP BY`? In what way does this not work?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you intend conditional aggregation like this:

```
select sum(case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then Value end) as Value , 
       sum(case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then Discount end) as Discount , 
       sum(case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then Net end) as Net, 
       sum(case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then Paid end) as Paid, 
       sum(case when Table1.TypeID in ( 1 ,3 ) then Rest end) as Rest
```